# Multiple titles for a set of graphs in R

Tags: r, graph, label

I have a set of 9 graphs that I need to arrange in a 3x3 grid in R.
I've made the graphs using ggplot then tried using grid.arrange from the gridExtra package but I can't seem to do the following:

- Have 3 titles, one per column
- Place a divider between the 3 columns

Currently my code is:

```
grid.arrange(Plot1, Plot4, Plot7,
             Plot2, Plot5, Plot8,
             Plot3, Plot6, Plot9,
             left="SD", 
             bottom="Time (Seconds)",)
```

Is there a simple way to do this? The dividers aren't too much of an issue but having the three titles is the main problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the `patchwork` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you give nrow ,and ncol parameters, also there is a comma at the end of the function.

```
grid.arrange(Plot1, Plot4, Plot7,
         Plot2, Plot5, Plot8,
         Plot3, Plot6, Plot9,
         left="SD", 
         bottom="Time (Seconds)",nrow = 3,ncol = 3)
```